# Recycling old answers

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, metapuzzles, connect-wall

Each of the puzzles below gives a **two-word answer**. Solve the puzzles and arrange the resulting 16 words into four groups of four, each with a common theme. The resulting group names form a clue for the **final answer**.

> 1. [Written every which way](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81142)
> 2. [A manager's dilemma](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81143)
> 3. [Keeping you safe](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81144)
> 4. [Coordinated efforts](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81145)
> 5. [Contours of a clandestine nature](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81146)
> 6. [Between two walls](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81147)
> 7. [Pulling a fast one](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81148)
> 8. [In excess I'm lethal](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/81149)

Comment: I did wonder what was going on.

Comment: Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D

Comment: Each puzzle is a stand alone, so I'm ok with it.

Comment: @North I see what you mean. I thought about posting one big puzzle, but navigating the partials would have gotten confusing pretty fast... There's already a wiki answer below listing the solutions so far.

Comment: I like it @jafe.  Well done.

Comment: Ugh, I really want to retract that downvote

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The four groups are:

1

> **London:** Fire, Marathon, Olympics, Underground

2

> **Tower:** Cell, [Devils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devils_Tower), Ivory, Water

3

> **Guard:** Coast, National, Old, Security - thanks @arbitrahj for this one

4

> **Duty:** Cycle, Double, Heavy, Line

The answers spell out

> London Tower Guard Duty, which seems to be hinting at the [**Yeomen Warders**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yeomen_Warders), whose duty it is to guard the Tower of London.

Comment: This is the intended answer. Well done!

Answer (score 12):

Aggregated Answers from the Puzzles:

1. Written every which way

   > Ivory Coast
2. A manager's dilemma

   > Fire Devils
3. Keeping you safe

   > National Security
4. Coordinated efforts -

   > Old Olympics
5. Contours of a clandestine nature

   > Underground Line
6. Between two walls

   > Cell Cycle
7. Pulling a fast one

   > Double Marathon
8. In excess I'm lethal

   > Heavy Water

Answer (score 4):

Some initial guesses:

1.

> **Life** Line, Cycle, Double, Cell.

2.

> **Guard** Old, National, Security, Coast

3.

> **Medal**(metal) Heavy, Devils, underground, olympics

4. ??? Kinda falls apart

> *red white and blue??* Fire Water, Ivory, marathon

Or

> **rings** fire, olympics, underground, cell

Which moves

> Water to life

Leaving

> Heavy, devils, ivory, marathon which is still ?????

Answer (score 2):

Possible Groupings [1,2,3,4 contradict with each other, just listing some possible combinations]

1:

> **Lines/Contours:** Coast, Line, Marathon, ?

2:

> **Sports [unlikely]:** Olympics, Marathon, ?, ?

3:

> **Metal**: Devils (devils metal: silver), Heavy (heavy metal), Underground?, ?

4:

> **Loops:** Cycle, Olympics (5 cicles on flag), Underground (System map looks like a loop), ?